# Bitdefender: Clear browser cache before system scan?

Tags: bitdefender

I tried to post this on the Bitdefender community, but there seems to be quite a delay. A commentor at `security.stackexchange.com` suggested posting here.

I installed Bitdefender Free for the first time today. The System Scan has been stuck at 8% for hours now. Web searching reveals that this is normal. I was wondering whether I should have cleared everything (caches, cookies, other temporary files) on all browsers before starting the scan. **Does Bitdefender ignore such ephemeral files?**

In KiloBytes, the folder `c:/Users/User.Name/AppData/Local/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/__________.default-release` contains the following folders, with size shown in kilobytes:

```
1086612 cache2
19232   startupCache
10140   safebrowsing
1380    personality-provider
661     shortcutCache
356     thumbnails
184     activity-stream.discovery_stream.json
32      jumpListCache
8       settings
```

I haven't checked across all browsers of all accounts, but the above browser and account is what I use most often.

Comment: How much space are your temp files taking up? Why did you install Bitdefender free? I like Bitdefender, but there's no free product that is any much better than the built in scanner in Windows.

Comment: I wanted to augment the Windows 10 AV because every AV will have blind spots. Better to have two. After the free period is over, I can use one as only on-demand (no real-time).  I added the info about the files used by Firefox.  The most obvious looking one is `cache2`.

Comment: It is not better to have two. AV products work, in part, by telling the OS to let them inspect files when an application requests them and before they are handed off to the requesting application. When you have two AV products they will fight over which gets to inspect the files. Windows Defender disables its real-time inspection when a second product is installed to prevent this happening. Unless you have a strong preference AND intend to pay for a 3rd party product, there is no benefit to having multiple AV products running simultaneously on your computer.

Comment: I mean having a 2nd AV for on-demand scan.

Comment: There are products designed just to do that. Good ones, such as MalwareBytes AntiMalware. BitDefender is designed to run full time, not on-demand. You can do what you want, but you came here for advice, and this is what I advise.

Comment: I asked whether Bitdefender ignores cache files.  I appreciate you sharing your opinion about high level strategies, but other experts in the industry have different outlooks.  That topic drifts very far from the question.